# Generate image from div (JSF, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, image, jsf, html

I am looking for a tool, with which I can render a an div with all inner elements and save it as an image. There is no PHP running on the Server, only Java Server Faces and some Javascript Code. Is there any tool to do that with the given resources?

Comment: can u elaborate your question, i didnt understand  **generate an image from an div with all inner elements** ?

Comment: I think he wants to render a piece of HTML and save it as an image using JSF or JS.

Comment: I built an preview of our Android application in HTML/CSS and I want to export this div (which contains an background image - the phone) and many other items in this div (icons, lists, etc) as an image
@iamdto: Yeah that's exactly what I want :O

Comment: @4ndro1d If you don't need to generate the image programmatically then just PrtScrn.

Comment: Problem is that PDF isnt able to render my gradients

Answer (score 2):

Convert the html to canvas first and then get the image of the canvas from the bitmapdata and then save it in the server side

This can be achieved through html2canvas http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: How should I convert it into a canvas?

Comment: @4ndro1d: The library html2canvas will do the trick. please follow the link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ls5Z6QE6
"The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java applets."